# How can I make it so that my logo on the top left of the page lines up with the text underneath it?

Tags: css, position, css-float, alignment, padding

How can I make it so that my logo on the top left of the page lines up with the text underneath it?  Also, I need the logo to stay lined up with the text underneath it regardless of what size i make the browser window.  I have tried changing the padding, margin, and float settings of the block_header class but the logo and text are not aligned if the browser window is not open to the correct size.  Here is my css:

```
.main {width:100%; padding:0; margin:0 auto; min-width: 1020px; overflow: hidden;}
.header { background:url(images/slider_bgpng200.png); background-repeat: repeat-x; padding:0; margin:0 auto; width: 100%; }
.header .headertop{width: 100%; background: #d3e5e8; height: 30px;}
.block_header {margin:0 auto; width:1200px; padding:0; border:none; }
.space { float:left; padding:0; margin:0; }
.header_text { width:200px; float:right; font:normal 11px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#9a9a9a; padding:6px 10px 10px 10px; margin:0; text-align:center;}
.slider { background: transparent; margin:0 auto; padding:0; height:420px;} 
.slider .gallery { margin:0 auto; width:980px; height:420px; padding:0;} 
.slider .textholder {padding-top: 110px; float: left; width: 44%; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 40px; color: #93a0a2;padding-left: 30px;}
.formbox{float: right; width: 48%; padding-top: 90px; padding-right: 40px;}
```

And here is the html:

```
<div class="main">
 <div class="header">
   <div class="headertop"> <img src="images/avidestlogo50perresave.png"  border="0" alt="logo" />
     <div class="header_text"><a href="#">Email</a> | <a href="#">Client Login</a> 
     </div>
   </div>
  <div class="block_header">
      <div class="space"><a href="index.html"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
         <div class="gallery">
            <div class="textholder">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Where Student and <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Alumni Freelancers <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;Get Hired
            </div>
            <div class = "formbox">Form is here
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The site is up at avidest.com/schneer so you can see what I am talking about.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A logo is often set up as a CSS background. You can then use a combination of  margin and padding to align the text within the element containing the background.

```
<div class="logo">Welcome to XYZ</div>
```

CSS:

```
.title {
     background-image:url(...);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     height:60px;
     padding-left:50px; <-- move the text to the right of the logo
     padding-top:10px; <-- add a bit of whitespace at the top
     ...font styling etc...
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried that but it still doesn't align with the text if you change the browser window size.